# Can I make a pure css tabbed border?

Tags: css

I want to give an element a border-top with a tab at the right corner like this:

[image]

Since this will be a repeated element within an Adobe Business Catalyst template, I want it to be pure CSS or at least CSS and javascript, without the use of any images. Is there any way this can be done?

Since it's just a decorative element, it doesn't have to be cross-browser.

Comment: Of course it can be done. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show the code you've attempted to achieve this so far so we can advise.

Comment: I don't know where to start, really. I tried applying a border to the right but that was bound to fail. It's easy to do using a div, but since it's meant to be a single element I can't use divs, and adding content with a pseudo element won't work since I can't style it.

Comment: Of course you can style pseudo-elements!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8hB7E/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="element">

</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body { background: #555 }

.element { background: #000; border-top: 2px solid #fff; height: 100px; position: relative; width: 300px; }

.element:after { background: #fff; content: " "; height: 10px; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; width: 20px; }
```

It utilises the :after pseudo-element (which I find to be really useful!)

For more info see here:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Unfortunately this won't work in IE7 or 6 - it's not core to the functionality of the website though, so I'd say it's ok as is.

Comment: This seems to be the perfect solution! Thanks!